# How do you send from code behind - signalR 1.0.1?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I have a situation where I am using signalR and asp.net. My implementation is very similar to chat example at [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr)

My question is how do I send from code behind? All examples use an older version of SignalR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your hub create a `void` like so:

```
public static void UpdateClients()
{
    var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NameOfHub>();
    context.Clients.All.ClientSideFunction();
}
```

then use as:

```
NameOfHub.UpdateClients();
```

Comment: Please explain second part. I am getting compile errors. I cannot use the Classname of the Hub.

Comment: are they both in the same namespace? if not you'll need to do that. what's the error message you're getting?

Comment: Thank you it worked. The same namespace was needed so I used the string hubname instead to avoid namespace issue. I had been using the server side function name instead of the client side function name.

Comment: var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NameOfHub>();

Should be cached.

Comment: you could also do `.GetHubContext<Namespace.NameOfHub>()`